# whats the use of data adapter

Tags: c#, ado.net

Can anyone explain why an `SqlDataAdapter` is used in the following code? The code is working fine without this adapter.

Also, why do we use `DataAdapter`? Please help me to understand this `DataAdapter` usage.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.....\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=......;Integrated Security=True");
                con.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter da =new SqlDataAdapter(); // Why use `SqlDataAdapter` here?
                SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("insert into bhargavc values(" + textBox1.Text + "," + textBox2.Text + ");", con);
                var o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show(o + "record to be inserted");
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error in the code");
            }
        }      

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a `DataSet` anywhere in your code?  You would use the [DataAdapter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) to fill that `DataSet` via the `.Fill()` method.

Comment: Holy sql injection vulnerability, Batman! This code is practically begging to get hacked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several reasons to use a [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx):

1. You can't fill a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) without one.
2. When the adapter completes its `.Fill()` method, it will close the connection for you; you don't have to explicitly call the `.Close()` method on your connection object.  Although, it is still good practice to.

In your case, it isn't necessary to have one though.  But, if you did want to use one, the implementation would look like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();     
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

From there, there are further actions that you can take on the `ds` object like exporting to Excel via Interop, filling a `DataGridView` or even updating a database table.

Answer (score 6):

Data adapter works like a mediator between the database and the dataset.  However, a data adapter cant store data.  It just gives data from the database to the dataset.

**For Example:**

A water pipe is used to bring water from a source (well, pond, etc.) to a destination.  However, the pipe isn't used to store water.  In the same way, a data adapter (like a water pipe) sends data from the database to a dataset.

This should give a clearer understanding about data adapters.

Answer (score 5):

A data adapter is used to read data from a data reader into a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) or a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx).

As you are not reading any data from the database in this code, the data adapter is completely superflous.

---

As a side note, you should use parameters instead of putting values directly into the query. Your code is totally open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: very useful note about sql injection

Answer (score 0):

1. To fill either `dataset` or `datatable`
2. You don't have to close your SQL connection explicitly like `.Close()`